# How can I add in multiple items in model by using array method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an original code as below which is working properly:-

```
- (ZYSideSlipFilterRegionModel *)commonFilterRegionModelWithKeyword:(NSString *)keyword selectionType:(CommonTableViewCellSelectionType)selectionType {
    ZYSideSlipFilterRegionModel *model = [[ZYSideSlipFilterRegionModel alloc] init];
    model.containerCellClass = @"SideSlipCommonTableViewCell";
    model.regionTitle = keyword;
    model.customDict = @{REGION_SELECTION_TYPE:@(selectionType)};
    model.itemList = @[[self createItemModelWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Local"] itemId:@"0" selected:NO],
    [self createItemModelWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Oversea"] itemId:@"1" selected:NO]];
    return model;
}
```

Now, I plan to change the static value (Oversea / local) to dynamic value. But only 1 item will be displayed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < filteredArray.count; i++) {
    int intItemID = i + 1;
    NSString *myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intItemID];
    model.itemList = @[[self createItemModelWithTitle:[filteredArray[i] valueForKey:@"attribute_name"] itemId:myNewString selected:NO] ];
}
```

How can I put 2 item in model.itemList? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What Type is itemList? NSArray or NSMutableArray?

Comment: can you show me method for : createItemModelWithTitle ?

Comment: @DungeonDev is an NSArray

Comment: @Anita, - (CommonItemModel *)createItemModelWithTitle:(NSString *)itemTitle
                                       itemId:(NSString *)itemId
                                     selected:(BOOL)selected {
    CommonItemModel *model = [[CommonItemModel alloc] init];
    model.itemId = itemId;
    model.itemName = itemTitle;
    model.selected = selected;
    return model;
}

Comment: You can use dictionary here , you can create dict like this     

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:@"test title" forKey:@"Title"];
    [dict setValue:@"Item Name" forKey:@"itemName"];
    [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"selected"];
    
    [filteredArray addObject:dict];


----------

You can fetch dict like this :

 NSMutableDictionary *dict  = (NSMutableDictionary *)filteredArray[i];

and pass your dictionary to  *createItemModelWithTitle* and fetch values over there

Comment: @Anita, Hi, I hit this error when i try to apply `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'`

Comment: use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray

Comment: Yes, you have to use a NSMutableArray as stated by Anita.

Comment: sorry for my stupid question, after apply NSMutableArray, how can I pass to createItemModelWithTitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this way

//step:1 fetch Dictionary like this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < filteredArray.count; i++) 
{

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)filteredArray[i] ;
    int intItemID = i + 1;
    NSString *myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intItemID];
    model.itemList = @[[self createItemModelWithTitle:dict];
}
```

//Step 2 : You can define your method for Model Like this

```
- (CommonItemModel *)createItemModelWithTitle:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictModel
 {

    CommonItemModel *model = [[CommonItemModel alloc] init];
    model.itemId = [dictModel valueForKey : @"itemId"];
    model.itemName = [dictModel valueForKey:@"itemTitle"];
    model.selected = [dictModel valueForKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool: 
    [[dictModel valueForKey:@"selected"]]]];

    return model;

 }
```

//One more thing you are write this in first step

```
    model.itemList = @[[self createItemModelWithTitle:dict];

But the method only return the Model class (CommonItemModel) so if you need any help you shared here
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Anita, thanks for your prompt action. I have few questions from your answer:-
1) `NSString *myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intItemID];` declare but unuse?
2) `model.itemList = @[[self createItemModelWithTitle:dict];` should be `model.itemList = @[[self createItemModelWithTitle:dict]];` ?
3) `model.selected = [dictModel valueForKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:
                                             [[dictModel valueForKey:@"selected"]]]];` hit error expected identifier. 
May I know how to solve these? thanks

Comment: you can add intItemID into dictionary so that you can add id in model class

Comment: See you have to change lil bit of my code according to your needs

Comment: If you still need help , i am here to help you :)

Comment: i get your overall idea. But now I facing another issue is only 1 item will be loaded in `model.itemList = @[[self createItemModelWithTitle:dict];` how can I make it load twice if i have 2 item count?

Comment: Here you just need to run a loop 
NAMutableArray *modelClassArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 for (int i = 0; i < filteredArray.count; i++) 
{

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)filteredArray[i] ;
    int intItemID = i + 1;
    NSString *myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intItemID];
   modelClassArray.add([self createItemModelWithTitle:dict]);
}

 model.itemList = modelClassArray;

Comment: Please try this and if helps you please upvote my answer

Comment: I hit `Property 'add' not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *'`, may i know how to solve?

Comment: share your code in one file -- share google drive link so i can check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184480/discussion-between-henry-and-anita).

Comment: i have shared code in chat room , you can check there